# Under-damped cosine signal estimation

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, estimation, fast-fourier-transform

I have *N* measurements of an under-damped cosine signal, represented by the equation $$ x(t) = Ae^{-\alpha t} \cos(2 \pi ft) $$ where $ A $ is a known constant. My objective is to estimate the remaining parameters $ \alpha $ and $ f $ using the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).

The Fourier transform that I have computed is given by:
$$ A \frac{1}{2\pi} \alpha \left[ \frac{1}{(\omega - 2\pi f)^2 + \frac{\alpha^2}{4\pi^2}} + \frac{1}{(\omega + 2\pi f)^2 + \frac{\alpha^2}{4\pi^2}} \right] $$

As I recall, this expression corresponds to a sum of two Lorentzian functions, where $ \omega = 2\pi f $

It's important to note that my sampling frequency is $ \frac{1}{0.01665} $ Hz.

I'm currently facing challenges in finding an appropriate fitting curve in the frequency domain, from which I'll be able to extract $\alpha$ and $f$.
Could someone please help me with this matter?

Comment: Is your fitting curve not just the Fourier transform you've calculated?

Comment: No, since these are measurment and have some errors. They do not "belong" to the same sunction. That's why a fitting is required.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're trying to fit to the fourier transform to extract the parameters. I would just fit the data with uncertainties to that function using numpy and extract the fit parameters with uncertainties. If you're worried about discretization effects, then maybe calculate FFTs of idealized sampled signals and fit to those? I don't know of a standard way to do that, but it could easily be brute forced if you have compute time to burn.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would like to do the fitting in frequency domain?

Comment: Hi guys,
I've thought that in the frequency domain it will be easier to do.
won't it?